# How to add 1 (increment) to the current value of a SharePoint list number field using the rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, updatelistitems

I am implementing a custom solution on SharePoint Online and want to add 1 (increment) to the current value of a specific field number (TotalViews) using rest API.

```
function UpdateViewsinHow(param)
 {
        var data = {
            __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.HowListListItem' },

           TotalViews : TotalViews+1  // here how to add 1 to current Totalviews
           
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('HowList')/items("+param+")",
            method: "PATCH",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
               "IF-MATCH": "*",
               "X-HTTPS-Method": "MERGE"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // confirm
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
}
```

Any advice to achieve this step?

Comment: You have to first fetch the current value of number column and then update it. Do you have current value of number column in `TotalViews` variable (or any other variable) in your code? I am guessing you must be showing the current value somewhere in your application??

Comment: I did not retrieve the value of TotalViews in this context, but I asked about if we could increment by 1 during the update process using something like the operator (@) or anything else, but if there is not, I will continue with your suggestion, which is also in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ganesh Sanap mentioned in the comments, you have to retrieve the current value to be able to add one and increment it, before you update it.

To do that, you can nest what you currently have inside the `success` function of a request to get the current value of `TotalViews`:

```
function UpdateViewsinHow(param) {
    // first get the current value of TotalViews
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('HowList')/items(" + param + ")?$select=TotalViews",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var update = {
                __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.HowListListItem' },
                
                // you may have to adjust this to get to the value of TotalViews
                // in the response, but it should be something close to this:
                TotalViews: response.d.TotalViews + 1

            };
            $.ajax({
                url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('HowList')/items(" + param + ")",
                method: "PATCH",
                data: JSON.stringify(update),
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "IF-MATCH": "*",
                    "X-HTTPS-Method": "MERGE"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // confirm
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you and @Ganesh Sanap